# How to two-way bind an array of objects to child component from parent component in angular 2

Tags: angular

I have a parent component which has an array of objects

```
this.arr = [
{
   style :'sample.css',
   disabled : this.formControl.valid
},
{
    style : 'sample.css',
    disabled : this.formControl.valid
}];
```

Note : this.formControl.valid indicates whether is form is dirty or not.

I am passing this array to child component

```
<child-component [controlConfiguration] ='arr'></child-component>
```

In child component i have exposed an Input variable

```
export class ChildComponent{
       @Input()
       controlConfiguration : any;
}
```

ChildComponent has following html

```
<div>
   <button *ngFor='let item of controlConfiguration'  [disabled]='!item.disabled' ></button>
</div>
```

changes are not propagated from parent component to child component as expected result is button should get enable as soon as form gets valid.

How to do this....??>

Comment: `let arr` indicates that this is a local variable. The `arr` in `[controlConfiguration] ='arr'` refers to `this.arr` so you need to bind to `this.arr = [..`

Comment: it is this.arr only I have updated question.

Comment: can you create a plunker?

Comment: @Maximus Hi i have created plunker : https://plnkr.co/edit/YWQ7Fc4ELYNjW7vg3J4w?p=preview

basically i just want parent component's input text to be reflected in child component input provided child component accepts an array of objects

Comment: hey, did [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45018879/2545680) help?

Comment: yes.. it helped me find my solution. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to update property `displayText` of `this.arr` every time the input value is changed because `this.inputText` is a primitive. I've added `(ngModelChange)="update($event)` and `update(value) {...}` method:

```
<input type='text' [(ngModel)]='inputText' (ngModelChange)="update($event)">
...
export class ParentComponent {
  inputText : string;

  arr = [{
    displayText : this.inputText
  },{
    displayText : this.inputText
  }];

  update(value) {
    this.arr[0].displayText = value;
    this.arr[1].displayText = value;
  }
```

Here is the [working plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/GwRYsYXd3zA4x8uSkxgZ?p=preview).